# Accessing Docker Hub behind Nginx

Tags: docker, nginx

I tried to access Docker Hub through an nginx proxy.

The following is my nginx proxy configuration.

```
 server {
        listen       800 ssl;
        ssl on;
        server_name nginx2 ;
        client_max_body_size 0;
        ssl_protocols             SSLv3 SSLv2 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_certificate            ssl/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key        ssl/cert.key;
        location / {
                proxy_pass https://{dockerhub_host};
                proxy_ssl_server_name on;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;   # Required for Docker client sake
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        }
}
```

I have tried both `registry-1.docker.io` and `hub.docker.com` in the place of `{dockerhub_host}` in the configuration.

Now I tried to log into Docker Hub using the following command.

```
docker login localhost:800
```

The following error was thrown:

> Error response from daemon: login attempt to `http://localhost:800/v2/ failed with status: 400 Bad Request`

And the following are the logs of the nginx proxy:

```
proxy_1  | 2018/06/12 22:24:42 [error] 5#5: *1 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 172.21.0.1, server: nginx2, request: "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://34.232.188.57:80/v2/", host: "localhost:800"
proxy_1  | 2018/06/12 22:24:42 [warn] 5#5: *1 upstream server temporarily disabled while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 172.21.0.1, server: nginx2, request: "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://34.232.188.57:80/v2/", host: "localhost:800"
proxy_1  | 2018/06/12 22:24:42 [error] 5#5: *1 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 172.21.0.1, server: nginx2, request: "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://52.3.45.201:80/v2/", host: "localhost:800"
proxy_1  | 2018/06/12 22:24:42 [warn] 5#5: *1 upstream server temporarily disabled while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 172.21.0.1, server: nginx2, request: "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://52.3.45.201:80/v2/", host: "localhost:800"
proxy_1  | 2018/06/12 22:24:42 [error] 5#5: *1 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 172.21.0.1, server: nginx2, request: "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://54.209.102.157:80/v2/", host: "localhost:800"
proxy_1  | 2018/06/12 22:24:42 [warn] 5#5: *1 upstream server temporarily disabled while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 172.21.0.1, server: nginx2, request: "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://54.209.102.157:80/v2/", host: "localhost:800"
proxy_1  | 172.21.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2018:22:24:42 +0000] "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1" 502 173 "-" "docker/18.03.1-ce go/go1.9.5 git-commit/9ee9f40 kernel/4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/18.03.1-ce \x5C(darwin\x5C))" "-"
proxy_1  | 2018/06/12 22:24:42 [error] 5#5: *5 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 172.21.0.1, server: nginx2, request: "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://docker_host/v2/", host: "localhost:800"
proxy_1  | 172.21.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2018:22:24:42 +0000] "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1" 502 173 "-" "docker/18.03.1-ce go/go1.9.5 git-commit/9ee9f40 kernel/4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/18.03.1-ce \x5C(darwin\x5C))" "-"
proxy_1  | 172.21.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2018:22:24:42 +0000] "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1" 400 271 "-" "docker/18.03.1-ce go/go1.9.5 git-commit/9ee9f40 kernel/4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/18.03.1-ce \x5C(darwin\x5C))" "-"
proxy_1  | 172.21.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2018:22:24:42 +0000] "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1" 400 271 "-" "docker/18.03.1-ce go/go1.9.5 git-commit/9ee9f40 kernel/4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/18.03.1-ce \x5C(darwin\x5C))" "-"
```

At first, I thought the error is thrown as I am accessing port 80. So, I have set the port to 443 explicitly like,

```
>proxy_pass https://hub.docker.com:443

>proxy_pass https://registry-1.docker.io:443
```

and tried the login command now. I still see the same error. Following are the logs of the nginx proxy:

```
proxy_1  | 172.21.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2018:22:33:09 +0000] "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1" 503 119 "-" "docker/18.03.1-ce go/go1.9.5 git-commit/9ee9f40 kernel/4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/18.03.1-ce \x5C(darwin\x5C))" "-"
proxy_1  | 172.21.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2018:22:33:09 +0000] "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1" 503 119 "-" "docker/18.03.1-ce go/go1.9.5 git-commit/9ee9f40 kernel/4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/18.03.1-ce \x5C(darwin\x5C))" "-"
proxy_1  | 172.21.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2018:22:33:09 +0000] "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1" 400 271 "-" "docker/18.03.1-ce go/go1.9.5 git-commit/9ee9f40 kernel/4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/18.03.1-ce \x5C(darwin\x5C))" "-"
proxy_1  | 172.21.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2018:22:33:09 +0000] "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1" 400 271 "-" "docker/18.03.1-ce go/go1.9.5 git-commit/9ee9f40 kernel/4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/18.03.1-ce \x5C(darwin\x5C))" "-"
```

**Output of `docker version`**

```
Client:
 Version:      18.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.37
 Go version:   go1.9.5
 Git commit:   9ee9f40
 Built:        Thu Apr 26 07:13:02 2018
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64
 Experimental: false
 Orchestrator: swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      18.03.1-ce
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.5
  Git commit:   9ee9f40
  Built:        Thu Apr 26 07:22:38 2018
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: true
```

**Output of `docker info`**

```
Containers: 2
 Running: 2
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 44
Server Version: 18.03.1-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 773c489c9c1b21a6d78b5c538cd395416ec50f88
runc version: 4fc53a81fb7c994640722ac585fa9ca548971871
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs
Operating System: Docker for Mac
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 1.952GiB
Name: linuxkit-025000000001
ID: OCVQ:XRBF:3H7P:PB3A:YQUH:FU2O:6BVB:BMHR:G7HX:UK63:SDKU:NPVI
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 39
 Goroutines: 63
 System Time: 2018-06-13T23:16:57.569645612Z
 EventsListeners: 3
HTTP Proxy: docker.for.mac.http.internal:3128
HTTPS Proxy: docker.for.mac.http.internal:3129
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

---

**Update**

I got the login thing working with the help of Tarun's solution. I now tried to pull/push images to the hub.docker.com site, but with no luck.

```
> docker push localhost:800/nadella/hello-world

Error:

The push refers to repository [localhost:800/nadella/helloworld]
2b8cbd0846c5: Pushing [==================================================>]  3.584kB
unauthorized: authentication required
```

logs:

```
proxy_1  | 172.21.0.1 - - [14/Jun/2018:04:57:26 +0000] "POST /v2/nadella/helloworld/blobs/uploads/ HTTP/1.1" 202 0 "-" "docker/18.03.1-ce go/go1.9.5 git-commit/9ee9f40 kernel/4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/18.03.1-ce \x5C(darwin\x5C))" "-"
proxy_1  | 172.21.0.1 - - [14/Jun/2018:05:00:09 +0000] "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1" 401 87 "-" "docker/18.03.1-ce go/go1.9.5 git-commit/9ee9f40 kernel/4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/18.03.1-ce \x5C(darwin\x5C))" "-"
proxy_1  | 172.21.0.1 - - [14/Jun/2018:05:00:10 +0000] "HEAD /v2/nadella/helloworld/blobs/sha256:9bb5a5d4561a5511fa7f80718617e67cf2ed2e6cdcd02e31be111a8d0ac4d6b7 HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "docker/18.03.1-ce go/go1.9.5 git-commit/9ee9f40 kernel/4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/18.03.1-ce \x5C(darwin\x5C))" "-"
proxy_1  | 172.21.0.1 - - [14/Jun/2018:05:00:11 +0000] "POST /v2/nadella/helloworld/blobs/uploads/?from=helloworld&mount=sha256%3A9bb5a5d4561a5511fa7f80718617e67cf2ed2e6cdcd02e31be111a8d0ac4d6b7 HTTP/1.1" 401 307 "-" "docker/18.03.1-ce go/go1.9.5 git-commit/9ee9f40 kernel/4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/18.03.1-ce \x5C(darwin\x5C))" "-"
proxy_1  | 172.21.0.1 - - [14/Jun/2018:05:00:11 +0000] "POST /v2/nadella/helloworld/blobs/uploads/ HTTP/1.1" 202 0 "-" "docker/18.03.1-ce go/go1.9.5 git-commit/9ee9f40 kernel/4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/18.03.1-ce \x5C(darwin\x5C))" "-"
```

I looked at `~/.docker/config.json`

```
{
        "auths": {
                "localhost:800": {}
        },
        "HttpHeaders": {
                "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/18.03.1-ce (darwin)"
        },
        "credsStore": "osxkeychain"
}
```

I even added "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {} to the configuration file and checked. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you need is below

```
location / {
     proxy_pass https://registry-1.docker.io:443;
}
```

Sending it the rest of the headers is not needed, because that you do when it's your own service. And then it works

[image: Login]

**Update 1**

You need to use the below configuration to pass on the authorization headers with the requests as well

```
location / {
   client_max_body_size 1024M;
   proxy_pass https://registry-1.docker.io:443;
   proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
   proxy_pass_header  Authorization;
   proxy_redirect https://registry-1.docker.io $scheme://$http_host;
}
```

Once you do that it works like a charm.

[image: Docker push]

[image: Docker repository]

Comment: Thanks Tarun. Do you know how to push/pull images now using this setup. I have tried few things, but with no luck. Updated the details at the end of the question.

Comment: I think auth is not getting passed let me check

Comment: yes. pull from official and public repositories seems to be working fine as they dont need auth(private repository may fail). push is failing. Not sure how to configure that.

Comment: Wow. Thanks a ton. This is perfect. How did you come up with some thing like that? I have been going through all the nginx docs, but no where close to coming up something up. Thanks again.

Comment: @starkk92, it just about understanding how things work. The more clearer picture you have, easier it becomes to approach a problem. And SO contributes a lot to increase that understanding and knowledge

Comment: What is the use of proxy_redirect here?

Comment: @starkk92, that helps when there are redirects, you need to change the location on the redirect header `Location`. This directive tells what needs to replaced in the header with what. `proxy_redirect <original text> <replacement text>;`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know or understand why you are trying to serve `hub.docker.com` via a reverse proxy, but, regarding your configuration:

There are a couple of errors:

First, you are missing the **ssl** parameter for the virtualhost listening port, as in the [official documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html):

```
server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate     www.example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ...
}
```

Then, you are defining the **virtualhost** as "*nginx2*", but calling it with "*localhost*" on the command. This might still be working because it's the only vhost, you are runnning it in the same machine and may be acting as the default one, however, it's wrong.

You should use localhost or the IP address as *server_name* if you want to use it that way, or better yet, set a DNS for ***nginx2*** in your local network (also you could add the name to the */etc/hosts* file if you want a quick workaround).

Comment: Hi, I am trying to do something like what Jfrog does. I have tried that ssl thing before with no luck. Rest of the things like adding dns and all are yet to be done but I am still trying locally and I don't see a problem.

Comment: Well, the error you are having here it's because of SSL misconfiguration, it might be that you need to generate the certificates (calling the parameter "ssl thing" makes me think you might be missing half the configuration for SSL to work). Do the cert.pem and cert.key exist? Did you generate them? Also you seem to be connecting to the upstream on the port **:80** while using **https**, which will fail. Although hub.docker.com supports https, but it's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes. I have tried all these things. Updated the post with more details. Thanks.

Comment: You can see here:  `upstream: "https://34.232.188.57:80/v2/", host: "localhost:800"` that you are trying to connect with **HTTPS** to an **HTTP** service.  That **wont** work. Also, Docker.com doesn't like being accessed through their IP address, so they will present an invalid SSL certificate. I still don't understand why would you want to masquerade hub.docker.com through a reverse proxy.

Comment: If you go further down in the question, I have uploaded the details of "https://34.232.188.57:443/v2/" which is not working either. As I have already said, I am trying to replicate the use case of Jfrog and Sonatype.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by replicate jfrog and sonatype, but I'm guessing you are missing some steps on the docker-registry setup. One last try, if i'm getting the errors right, you are still sending http due to the docker login, try this: `docker login https://localhost:800`

Comment: Thanks for taking time and going through the question. The idea is to setup multiple local/private and remote registries(docker hub, google container registry etc) behind reverse proxy. You can read more about it and the uses of this setup here https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Docker+Registry

Comment: What *"ssl parameter"*? Are you referring to parameter "`listen`"? Can you make it clearer (by editing your answer)?